# Visual Studio XAML website. Xaml won't load

Tags: xaml

Following .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Vowels.aspx.cs" Inherits="XMLPraktijkOpdrachtJavascript.Vowels" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Vowels</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Vowels.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="VowelsPage" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-silverlight">                
            <param name="source" value="Xaml/Vowels.xaml"/>             
        </object>                   
    </body>
</html>
```

Uses this xaml file:

http://pastebin.com/1sFX93Bp (it's a bit long to post here)

But my page simply won't load. It says white. If I comment out everything from line 20 however, it does work (ie: the remaining code executes).

What could be the problem, or are there any decent Xaml debuggers out there? Since Visual Studio won't let you put breakpoints in xaml files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you please change this

```
TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"
```

to

```
TargetType="TextBlock"
```

and also you need to remove

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3B596E"/>
<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3B5940"/>
```

and change

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24px"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14px"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14px"/>
```

to

```
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
```

The complete xaml script is shown as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

  Loaded="OnLoaded">

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="600"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="Red"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF3B596E" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="TitleText"
             TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="24"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MidnightBlue"/>
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="LabelText"
             TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFB3B4C1"/>
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

            </Style>
            <Style x:Key="ValueText"
             TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe Black"/>
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Ivory"/>
                <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>

            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush>
                <GradientStop Color="#93C5E8"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#3B596E" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="70"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Style="{StaticResource TitleText}">
                    Vowel Details
        </TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Strings with frequency &gt; 50</TextBlock>
        <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Content="Sort"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="4"
           Name="btnSort50"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">128</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Starting with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">51</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">12</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">22</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">7</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">7</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">3</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Ending with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">52</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="2" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">7</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">27</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="4" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">5</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">9</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="6" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">4</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Strings with frequency &gt; 40</TextBlock>
        <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Content="Sort"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="10"
           Name="btnSort40"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">182</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Starting with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">78</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">15</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">36</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="10" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="10" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">13</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="11" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="11" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">10</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="12" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="12" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">4</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Ending with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">75</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="8" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">14</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="9" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">38</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="10" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="10" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">8</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="11" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="11" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">10</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="12" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="12" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">5</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="13" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Strings with frequency &gt; 30</TextBlock>
        <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Content="Sort"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="16"
           Name="btnSort30"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="13" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">247</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="13" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Starting with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="13" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">100</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="14" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="14" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">18</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="15" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="15" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">48</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="16" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="16" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">19</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="17" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="17" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">11</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="18" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="18" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">4</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="13" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Ending with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="13" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">103</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="14" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="14" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">19</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="15" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="15" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">55</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="16" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="16" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">10</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="17" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="17" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">13</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="18" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="18" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">6</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="19" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Strings with frequency &gt; 20</TextBlock>
        <Button Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Content="Sort"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Grid.Row="22"
           Name="btnSort20"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="19" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">392</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="19" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Starting with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="19" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">170</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="20" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="20" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">34</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="21" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="21" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">77</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="22" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="22" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">29</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="23" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="23" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">21</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="24" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="24" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">9</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="19" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">Ending with a Vowel</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="19" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">161</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="20" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">a</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="20" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">27</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="21" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">e</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="21" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">81</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="22" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">i</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="22" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">24</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="23" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">o</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="23" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">20</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="24" Style="{StaticResource LabelText}">u</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="24" Style="{StaticResource ValueText}">9</TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately that does not fix it.

The page stays completely white and my OnLoad event doesn't trigger.

Comment: Is there an alternative to

<Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF3B596E"/> ?

Because I need to have a background with this colour.

Comment: is there a yellow warning icon on the bottom left of your page? if so what's the error msg? also you can't have a background color for your TextBlock, you need to change the TextBlock to a Label.

Comment: No, there are no yellow or red warnings. Everything compiles just fine.

I found out the problem lies with the Button, but even a simple <Button /> is not recognized by silverlight and the page doesn't load.

Comment: okay, looks like you have a reference problem, can you check if you have this assembly System.Windows.Controls?

Comment: pls also take a look at this post http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/t/15533.aspx

Comment: No, it doesn't seem I don't have that assembly, and it seems I can't add it either... Other than that, I am using the latest version of Silverlight, so Button should be supported.

Comment: you are using Silverlight 1. as you defined application/x-silverlight. Buttons are not supported in Silverlight 1. change it to application/x-silverlight-2 which is for silverlight 2/3/4.

Comment: please read the last 3 answers of this post, http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/137837/307800.aspx, 'You are using Silverlight Script Web and Button is not supported in your scenario', 'you may simulate a button with the panels you have available and handle MouseLeftButton down for click-type event'.