# Silverlight Button (with Xaml and C#)

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Test.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="XMLPraktijkOpdrachtJavascript.Test" %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Javascript/Test.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <object id="TestPage" width="100%" height="100%" type="application/x-silverlight-2">                
            <param name="source" value="Xaml/Test.xaml"/>               
        </object>                   
    </body>
</html>
```

Test.xaml page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

  Loaded="onLoaded">

    <Button Width="50" Height="50" Name="Test">TEST</Button>

</Grid>
```

Test.js file:

```
// Event function when page gets loaded
function onLoaded() {
    alert('In TestPage');
}
```

Without the button, it works fine. With the button, it fails. Why can't I use a button in Silverlight? The System.Windows.Controls is added to the project.

Comment: You've made a concious choice to use the older Javascript API and not build a full Silverlight Xap?  "it fails" is not really very useful to us to diagnose your problem please add more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having read [a very similar question you've asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748608/visual-studio-xaml-website-xaml-wont-load), I'm not sure you understand the fundamental difference between Silverlight 1 and Silverlight 2 or later.

Your `<object>` element has the attribute `type="application/silverlight-2"`, which specifies Silverlight 2 or later.  However, the `source` parameter specifies a `.xaml` file, which (I believe) is how Silverlight 1 works.

Silverlight 2 and later require the Silverlight code to be developed in a separate project.  These Silverlight projects compile all the Silverlight code into a  `.xap` file.  You then add the Silverlight application to your web project, which arranges for the compiled `.xap` file to be copied into a `ClientBin` folder within your web project.  You can then have your web project serve the `.xap` file to your browser.  With Silverlight 1, it appears that the `.xaml` files are served up from within your web project.

Is your project a Silverlight 1 project or not?  If it's an existing application, is there any chance of migrating it to a later version?  If you've been lumbered with maintaining a large legacy Silverlight 1 application, all I can say is I'm really sorry for you.

There is no good reason at all to write new Silverlight 1 applications any more.  It's fundamentally different to other versions of Silverlight and it has so many limitations.  In particular, there is no `Button` in Silverlight 1, as someone has already pointed out to you in a comment to your previous question.  This is likely to be the cause of the error you are seeing.

Comment: Blame the teacher I guess. We HAVE to use xaml files and he gives very little information about the who's and why's.

Comment: @Matthias: To be quite frank I'm shocked that you're being asked to learn Silverlight 1.  There's absolutely no value in learning it because it is effectively obsolete.  Schools and universities really should not be teaching it any more.  If your teacher won't change his mind about it, complain to his superiors.

Comment: Our school has a tendancy to teach us outdated technologies... Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

you can't just use a "xaml file" like that. You need a "silverlight project" that outputs a xap file which you can embed in your web page.

Try creating a silverlight application, this will create the silverilght project, prompt and create a web application for you, configure the web app to display the silverlight project and gets you up and running more quickly ;)

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible. It's a school assignment and we have to use a given template project. (Visual Studio 2010)

Comment: can't you add a Silverlight Project to your solution?

Comment: Can I still use the javascript as a code behind for my onload and onmousedown events then?